# Setting the x-axis range of a winform chart to be the most recent 10 seconds of a data stream

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that displays data in real time on a line chart. I am trying to set the range of this chart at 10 seconds. I want the maximum value of the chart to be the most recent data input, and the minimum value of the chart to be the data input from 10 seconds prior. However, I cannot set the range to be a 10 second interval. I have tried

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
DateTime minTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(-10);
DateTime maxTime = currentTime;
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Interval = 10;
```

I have also tried to make my chart area have one interval that is 10 seconds long, but have also been unsuccessful in doing so. I think this method might be easier, but any answer that allows me to display the most recent 10 seconds of my data would be much appreciated!

Comment: In what way does it not work for you? Note: You should not set the Interval  to 10 seconds unless you mean it as it means the the axis will only be get one label per 10 seconds, ie one label for your whole range. Instead set it to `1` or not at all to use the automatic interval..! Also: your code seems mixed up: what is that with `minTime ` and `minDate`?? I assumed typos and replaced `minTime` with `minDate ` etc and it works fine.

Comment: The typo was not made in my code I must've mistyped it when creating my question.  I was able to solve my issue though.

`chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Maximum = 500;
chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Minimum = 450;`

These three lines were all that were necessary for showing only the most recent 10 seconds of data.

Comment: Well, good for you if it works although hard-coding those numbers makes no sense to me..